# How to use getSelecteditem method

Tags: gwt

How to use getSelecteditem method for menubar object?

My code is here:

```
    final MenuBar f2=new MenuBar(true);

    Command cm=new Command(){
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Window.alert("hello");
    }
};
f2.addItem(prop.getProperty("Submenu1"),cm);
f2.addItem(prop.getProperty("Submenu2"),cm);
```

Comment: Looks like duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928310/getselecteditem-on-gwt-menubar

Comment: Here you are getting problem because you have added same Command for different menu items. If you create different menuitems and add them separately you wont find any problem. cheers !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
MenuBar menuList = new MenuBar(true);
menuList.setAutoOpen(true);

/**
 * First Menu Item
 */
MenuItem firstMenu = new MenuItem("First Menu", new Command() {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
       // write code for First Menu Click.
           doForFirstMenu();
    }
});
menuList.addItem(firstMenu );


/**
 * For Second Menu Item
 */
MenuItem secondMenu= new MenuItem("Second Menu", new Command() {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
       // Write code for second menu click.
       doForSecondMenu();
    }
});
menuList.addItem(secondMenu);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a seperate Command for each MenuItem!

```
final MenuBar f2 = new MenuBar(true);

Command cm = new Command() {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
    Window.alert("sub1");
    }
};
Command cm2 = new Command() {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
    Window.alert("sub2");
    }
};

f2.addItem("Submenu1", cm);
f2.addItem("Submenu2", cm2);
```